# Make data layer disappear and different one appear on click in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, layers

I'm mapping COVID vaccinations per state and per county in the US. I have state data as well as county data displaying properly.

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a state it zooms in to the selected state, turns off the state data layer and turns on the county data layer. So basically it goes from showing state data to county data.

How do I do this? Would I need to add something to the `zoomTofeature` function?

```
    var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [39.5, -95.3],
    zoom: 3.5,
  });

  // add basemap
  var Stamen_TonerLite = L.tileLayer(
    "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",
    {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-County/8xkx-amqh/data">County data</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc/data">State data</a> | Map: <a href="https://weircf.wixsite.com/e-portfolio">Chip Weir</a>',
      subdomains: "abcd",
      maxZoom: 19,
    }
  ).addTo(map);

  //zoom to a state, turn off state data, turn on county data
  function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  }

  //zoom to county
  function zoomToFeature1(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  }

  function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
      weight: 4,
      opacity: 1,
      color: "#dbff4d",
    });
    layer.bringToFront();
  }

  function highlightFeature1(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
      weight: 4,
      opacity: 1,
      color: "#dbff4d",
    });
    layer.bringToFront();
  }

  //reset the hightlighted states on mouseout
  function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojsonStates.resetStyle(e.target);
  }

  //reset the hightlighted counties on mouseout
  function resetHighlight1(e) {
    geojsonCounties.resetStyle(e.target);
  }

  //add these events to the layer object
  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature,
      click: zoomToFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight,
    });
  }

  //add these events to the layer object
  function onEachFeature1(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature1,
      click: zoomToFeature1,
      mouseout: resetHighlight1,
    });
  }

  function getColor(d) {
    return d > 70
      ? "#2c7bb6"
      : d >= 60
      ? "#abd9e9"
      : d >= 50
      ? "#fdae61"
      : d < 50
      ? "#d7191c"
      : "#5f5f5f";
  }

  function getColor1(d) {
    return d >= 75
      ? "#1a9641"
      : d >= 50
      ? "#a6d96a"
      : d >= 25
      ? "#fdae61"
      : d > 0
      ? "#d7191c"
      : "#5f5f5f";
  }

  function states(feature) {
    return {
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 1,
      color: "whitesmoke",
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.vaxData_states_Series_Complete),
    };
  }

  function counties(feature) {
    return {
      weight: 0.5,
      opacity: 0.5,
      color: "whitesmoke",
      fillOpacity: 0.75,
      fillColor: getColor1(feature.properties.vaxData_Series_Complete),
    };
  }

  // add state borders
  var geojsonStates = L.geoJson.ajax("data/us_states.geojson", {
    style: states,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  });

  geojsonStates.addTo(map);

  //add county geojson
  var geojsonCounties = L.geoJson.ajax("data/counties.geojson", {
    style: counties,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature1,
  });

  geojsonCounties.addTo(map);
```

Comment: In your ```zoomToFeature``` and ```zoomToFeature1``` you would need to toggle the layer (add / remove) it. There is also a handy plugin called [leaflet-layervisibilit plugin](https://github.com/phloose/leaflet-layervisibility) which extends ```L.Layer``` and ```L.LayerGroup``` (and```L.GeoJson```) with show / hide functions.

Comment: `map.removeLayer(layername)`

Comment: `map.removeLayer(layername)` worked, but I'd like for the state data to reappear on zoom out and for the county data not to appear until a state has been clicked on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the current zoom level when zoomed to a state using `stateZoomLevel = map.getBoundsZoom(e.target.getBounds());`. Then you need an event listener on `zoomend` and check if the stored zoom level is bigger than the current one. If so you need to hide the counties and show the states. Here is a sample using your code. I have used `fetch` to query the data and the [leaflet-layervisibility](http://github.com/phloose/leaflet-layervisibility) plugin for toggeling the layers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>make-data-layer-disappear-and-different-one-appear-on-click-in-leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Leaflet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Leaflet Visibility -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-layervisibility/dist/leaflet-layervisibility.js"></script>


  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map("map", {
      center: [39.5, -95.3],
      zoom: 3.5,
    });

    (async () => {
      let stateZoomLevel;

      // add basemap
      var Stamen_TonerLite = L.tileLayer(
        "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png", {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-County/8xkx-amqh/data">County data</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc/data">State data</a> | Map: <a href="https://weircf.wixsite.com/e-portfolio">Chip Weir</a>',
          subdomains: "abcd",
          maxZoom: 19,
        }
      ).addTo(map);

      //zoom to a state, turn off state data, turn on county data
      function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        showCountiesHideStates(e.target.feature.properties.STATE);

        // Save current Zoom Level
        stateZoomLevel = map.getBoundsZoom(e.target.getBounds());
      }

      //zoom to county
      function zoomToFeature1(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
      }

      // Event Listener
      map.on("zoomend", (x) => {
        if (stateZoomLevel > map.getZoom()) {
          showStatesHideCounties();
        }
      })

      function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 4,
          opacity: 1,
          color: "#dbff4d",
        });
        layer.bringToFront();
      }

      function highlightFeature1(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 4,
          opacity: 1,
          color: "#dbff4d",
        });
        layer.bringToFront();
      }

      //reset the hightlighted states on mouseout
      function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojsonStates.resetStyle(e.target);
      }

      //reset the hightlighted counties on mouseout
      function resetHighlight1(e) {
        geojsonCounties.resetStyle(e.target);
      }

      //add these events to the layer object
      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
          mouseover: highlightFeature,
          click: zoomToFeature,
          mouseout: resetHighlight,
        });
      }

      //add these events to the layer object
      function onEachFeature1(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
          mouseover: highlightFeature1,
          click: zoomToFeature1,
          mouseout: resetHighlight1,
        });
      }

      function getColor(d) {
        return d > 70 ?
          "#2c7bb6" :
          d >= 60 ?
          "#abd9e9" :
          d >= 50 ?
          "#fdae61" :
          d < 50 ?
          "#d7191c" :
          "#5f5f5f";
      }

      function getColor1(d) {
        return d >= 75 ?
          "#1a9641" :
          d >= 50 ?
          "#a6d96a" :
          d >= 25 ?
          "#fdae61" :
          d > 0 ?
          "#d7191c" :
          "#5f5f5f";
      }

      function states(feature) {
        return {
          weight: 3,
          opacity: 1,
          color: "whitesmoke",
          fillOpacity: 0.8,
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.vaxData_states_Series_Complete),
        };
      }

      function counties(feature) {
        return {
          weight: 0.5,
          opacity: 0.5,
          color: "whitesmoke",
          fillOpacity: 0.75,
          fillColor: getColor1(feature.properties.vaxData_Series_Complete),
        };
      }

      // add state borders
      const geojsonStatesData = await fetch("data/us_states.geojson").then(r => r.json());
      var geojsonStates = L.geoJson(geojsonStatesData, {
        style: states,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
      });

      geojsonStates.addTo(map);

      //add county geojson
      const geojsonCountiesData = await fetch("data/counties.geojson").then(r => r.json());
      var geojsonCounties = L.geoJson(geojsonCountiesData, {
        style: counties,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature1,
      });

      geojsonCounties.addTo(map);

      function showStatesHideCounties() {
        geojsonStates.show();
        geojsonCounties.hide();
      }

      function showCountiesHideStates(stateId) {
        if (stateId) {
          geojsonCounties.show((layer) => {
            return layer.feature.properties.STATE === stateId;
          });
        } else {
          geojsonCounties.show();
        }
        geojsonStates.hide();
      }

      // Init
      showStatesHideCounties();
    })();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @bloigge ! Is there a way I can make it so that if you zoom in to a certain level you see the county data? Cause when I zoom out after I click the state it shows state data but when I zoom in it doesn't switch to the county data. Should I start a separate question thread for that?

Comment: That's a different question. But it would be similar. You would need to have an event listener on ```zoomend``` and toggle your layers depending on the zoomlevel.